# CSS selector for disabled input type="submit"

Tags: css, css-selectors, submit-button

Is there a CSS selector for disabled `input type="submit"` or `"button"`?

Should I just use `input[type="submit"][disabled]`?

Does that work in IE6?

Comment: `:disabled` may be better, in CSS3. However IE doesn't support either so you'll need a backup class.

Comment: Thanks, good point, but I plan on staying away from CSS3 for now.

Comment: Developers really need to stop trying to support IE6. And site owners / managers really need to stop asking developers to support it. Come on people -- IE9 is coming out now!

Comment: Well, considering 24% of the users of my client come from IE6, I cannot ignore it for now sadly. IE9 is great, but it doesn't work on Windows XP for example.

Comment: 24% is above average for IE6 these days, but yes if you have that kind of stat you need to cope with. Doesn't mean you have to make everything look perfect in it though, as long as the functionality works. For what it's worth, we're seeing about 17%, and we've made a decision to actively drop support for it in our upcoming site revamp.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

> Does that work in IE6?

No, **IE6 does not support attribute selectors** at all, cf. *[CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#attributeselectors)*.

You might find *[How to workaround: IE6 does not support CSS “attribute” selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649341/how-to-workaround-ie6-does-not-support-css-attribute-selectors)* worth the read.

---

**EDIT**
*If* you are to ignore IE6, you could do (CSS2.1):

```
input[type=submit][disabled=disabled],
button[disabled=disabled] {
    ...
}
```

CSS3 (IE9+):

```
input[type=submit]:disabled,
button:disabled {
    ...
}
```

You *can* substitute `[disabled=disabled]` (attribute value) with `[disabled]` (attribute presence).

Comment: Ok, thank you. But if I was to ignore IE6, how would that be accomplished? Would input[type="button"[disabled] be standard?

Comment: Thanks again for the first link, CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer - EXCELLENT ARTICLE, instant bookmark.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper The attribute-based approach will work in IE8 (which is neither IE6 nor IE9+). Both IE7 and IE8 supports _some_ CSS2.1 and CSS3 selectors, attribute value / presence being one of those.

Answer (score 2):

As said by jensgram, IE6 does not support attribute selector. You could add a class="disabled" to select the disabled inputs so that this can work in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

I used @jensgram solution to hide a div that contains a disabled input. So I hide the entire parent of the input.

Here is the code :

```
div:has(>input[disabled=disabled]) {
    display: none;
}
```

Maybe it could help some of you.

Answer (score 0):

This is in 2021. This is the css selector, which worked for me on Chrome and Edge (IE seems to be not supported any longer: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/):

```
input[type=submit]:disabled {
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
}
```