# CSS selector for label using "for" attribute in IE 6,7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I have a label in my web page as label for="title"
How can i style this specific label element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to format an HTML tooltip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip)

Comment: Oh, my bad, I misunderstood the question. Sorry

Comment: How annoying that IE6 doesn't support basic CSS selectors. To be honest, I've given up trying to support IE6 now; it's just not worth the effort, and its market share is falling all the time. But if you do still have to support it, I feel for you.

Answer (score 7):

Since IE6 doesn't support attribute selectors, you might consider specifying a class attribute to your `<label />` and select it with it. (See [How to workaround: IE6 does not support CSS “attribute” selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649341/how-to-workaround-ie6-does-not-support-css-attribute-selectors))

With IE7, you could just do this:

```
label[for="title"] {
   font-weight: bold;
   /* ... */
}
```

See [jsfiddle.net/GWNXq](http://jsfiddle.net/GWNXq/3).

Answer (score 7):

you can assign it an id

```
<label for="title" id="label-title">TITLE</label>
```

then apply some css, eg

```
#label-title{font-weight:bold}
```

Comment: Pretty much one of the only (easy) ways to accommodate IE6. +1

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for ur answers!

This is what i found after hours of "googling"

I think in IE6 we must use id or class attributes otherwise its not possible to select the label element as said above in most of the anwers!

`label[htmlFor="title"]{... }` for IE7

`label[for="title"]{... }`for FF 3.5(I have not tested it on safari)

reference - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector

P.S: Its still not working in IE7!!

Answer (score 2):

Like Rocket Ronnie states, id is one way of doing it.

You can even supply a class, that way you can style several things at once

```
<label for="title" class="label">TITLE</label>
<label for="title" class="label">FORENAME</label>
```

then apply some css, eg

```
.label{font-weight:bold}
```