# how to convert mouse pointer arrow to hand onmouseover link or button.?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make mouse pointer a hand when hover over <li> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/make-mouse-pointer-a-hand-when-hover-over-li-element)

i want to convert a mouse pointer(arrow) into a hand (with finger) on over any link or button. I have seen many posts here on this site. but they all are either in asp.net or in other language. As i want to make this to happen only in javascript or css or php or combinations of these languages these posts was not helpful to me in any way. so Please help...

Comment: This has been discussed before. Please see *[Make mouse pointer a hand when hover over <li> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/make-mouse-pointer-a-hand-when-hover-over-li-element)*

Answer (score 4):

try this one  `a:hover,button:hover { cursor: pointer;}`

waiting for good news

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS:

```
a, button, input[type="submit"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But **IE6** doesnot support CSS selectors..(`input[type="submit"]`)

You might find [How to workaround: IE6 does not support CSS “attribute” selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649341/how-to-workaround-ie6-does-not-support-css-attribute-selectors) worth the read.

Answer (score 1):

anchor elements by default use a hand pointer.

CSS for buttons to also use a hand pointer:

```
button, 
input[type=submit], 
input[type=reset] {cursor:pointer;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/nZzkd/)

Answer (score 0):

To use with force full ***cursor pointer***

```
a,
button {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```